# Getting an API URL id from another API data not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, algorithm, next.js

In my small react Project, I needed to use an id from one api call in subsequent api calls. I have access to the data from the first call but do not know how to use it in the second call. I tried using a string literal to access all the ids so the URL can pick each ids directly from the other API but it was just returning random IDs.

Here is my code below

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
export default class Cat extends Component {
   state = {
   imagedata: [],
   data: [],
   CatWeight: "",
   CatMetric: "",

     }
   
componentDidMount(){
   this.fetchCountryData();
   this.fetchImageUrl();
}     


  fetchCountryData = async () => {
    const url = "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds";
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      const data = await response.data;
     console.log(data)
      this.setState({
        data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };


  fetchImageUrl = async () =>{
    
    // This is the Place I'm having issue with. The line below. where imgurl becomes https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?breed_id=char as an example
    // The id is coming from the First API id's
  const imgurl = `https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?breed_id=${this.state.data.map((item) => { return item.id })} ` 

 try {
    const response = await axios.get(imgurl);
    const imagedata = await response.data;
    console.log(imagedata)
    this.setState({
        imagedata,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

   
 render() {
   return (
     <div>
      {
            this.state.imagedata.map((item, id) =>{
            return <ul key={id}>{item.id}</ul>
            })
        
      }
      
     </div>
   )
 }
}
```

Comment: Is it just a typo?  The [catapi docs](https://docs.thecatapi.com/example-by-breed) use a plural on `breed_ids`, not the singular `breed_id`.  For example, `https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?breed_ids=siam`.

Comment: Also, it looks like all the data in the second call is already contained in the first.  For instance, `response[66]` has an `image` property which returns an object with `id`, `height`, `width`, and `url` properties.  It looks like this: `{height: 1203, id: "0SxW2SQ_S", url: "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/0SxW2SQ_S.jpg", width: 800}`.  Obviously if you're displaying one or more images, you will still need to actually fetch these urls.  But I'm not sure a separate API call is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know that specific api, but it looks like that endpoint would only take a single id. By using map, you are giving it an array of ids. You may need to make separate api calls for each id.

Comment: Yes, it does takes a single Id and that's why I'm trying to see if I can pass each Id from the first API using Map

Answer (score 0):

(**Note**: answer significantly updated in response to comment.)

There was a typo in your original.  I don't know if that was only in StackOverflow or if it's also in the code that's failing for you.  But the search URL looks like

```
https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?breed_ids=ebur
```

It's `breed_ids`, plural, not `breed_id`.  Also, it only takes a single breed id, not a list of them, so you will need separate calls for each.

In the majority of cases (64/67), the image URL is already in the response, and there's no reason to fetch it again.  So we can fetch it only for the few missing ones, and use `Promise.all` to combine them to handle the output.  Here's one technique that doesn't try to use your React setup, but a simple `innerHTML` atop some text manipulation, and using the native `fetch` instead of `axios`:

```js
fetch('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds')
  .then (resp => resp.json())
  .then (breeds => breeds .map (
    breed => 'image' in breed && 'url' in breed.image
      ? Promise .resolve ({name: breed.name, url: breed.image.url})
      : fetch (`https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?breed_ids=${breed.id}`)
          .then (resp => resp .json ())
          .then (res => ({name: breed.name, url: res[0].url}))
  ))
  .then (xs => Promise.all (xs))
  .then (breeds => breeds.map(
    breed => `<img src="${breed .url}" title="${breed .name}" width="100"/>`
  ).join (''))
  .then (pics => document .getElementById ('cats') .innerHTML = pics)
  .catch (err => console .log (`Error: ${err}`))
```

```html
<div id="cats"></div>
```

Because `Promise.all` accepts scalar values as well as Promises in its input array, we didn't have to wrap in `Promise`s those that were in the original document.  Instead of

```js
      ? Promise .resolve ({name: breed.name, url: breed.image.url})
```

we could have just written:

```js
      ? {name: breed.name, url: breed.image.url}
```

and it would be slightly more performant.  But I still prefer the version as written, just out of a desire for consistency.

Also, if you're working in an environment that supports the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (most but not yet all common environments), then this

```js
    breed => 'image' in breed && 'url' in breed.image
```

might be better written as

```js
    breed => breed?.image?.url
```

## Update -- Breaking this down

A comment asked for a code breakdown.  Here is an attempt:

```js
fetch('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds')
  .then (resp => resp.json())
```

We start by fetching the data and turning the result into an object.  I used the built-in [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) call rather than importing axios, but we could do something very similar with axios.

Note that we are using straight promises here, and not the `async-await` gloss on them.  This could certainly be rewritten in an `aysnc-await` style, but, especially when I'm using `Promise.all`, I don't see much advantage.

```js
  .then (breeds => breeds .map (
```

the result we get from the call is an array.  We use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on that array to turn an array of breeds into an array of something else, as seen in the next section:

```js
    breed => 'image' in breed && 'url' in breed.image
      ? Promise .resolve ({name: breed.name, url: breed.image.url})
      : fetch (`https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?breed_ids=${breed.id}`)
          .then (resp => resp .json ())
          .then (res => ({name: breed.name, url: res[0].url}))
  ))
```

Here we test if the object already has the URL property we want.  If it does, we return an already-resolved Promise for an object with `name` and `url` properties found in the breed object from the array.  If it doesn't (and there are only a few of these in my test), we construct the image search url for the breed, call `fetch` on that, and when the resulting promise resolves, we turn this response into an object with `resp .json ()`, and finally construct a `name`/`url` object from this.

In either branch of the conditional statement, we are returning a Promise.  So the result of this is an array of Promises.

```
  .then (xs => Promise.all (xs))
```

We use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to convert an array of Promises for our `name`/`url` objects into a Promise for an array of `name`/`url`  objects.  This Promise will resolve when all the Promises we supplied have resolved, and it will return an array with the results of the calls.  For instance, if we had this:

> ```js
> Promise.all([
>   new Promise ((res, rej) => setTimeout(res, 2000, 'foo')),
>   new Promise ((res, rej) => setTimeout(res, 3000, 'bar')),
>   new Promise ((res, rej) => setTimeout(res, 1000, 'baz')),
> ])
> ```

it would resolve (in three seconds, when the final promise resolves) to the array `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`.  And if we added this:

> ```js
>   new Promise ((res, rej) => setTimeout(rej, 2000, 'qux')),
> ```

then it would reject (in two seconds, when the first promise is rejected) with the value `'qux'`.

`Promise.all` is a real convenience.  We now have a Promise that when everything succeeds, gives us an array of breeds.

```js
  .then (breeds => breeds.map(
    breed => `<img src="${breed .url}" title="${breed .name}" width="100"/>`
  ).join (''))
  .then (pics => document .getElementById ('cats') .innerHTML = pics)
```

This just creates an HTML string and inserts it into the document.  You would need to consult your React documentation to find the equivalent asynchronous processing with React.  But it shouldn't be hard.

```js
  .catch (err => console .log (`Error: ${err}`))
```

Finally, if there's an error and one of the Promises can't be resolved, the rejection reason will come here.  You would presumably also handle this with a React technique.

Comment: Not all the images are embedded in the response. Some doesn't have the images. @Scott

Comment: @simplelife: Yes, you're right.  I was filtering those few out before, mistakenly believing that there was not an image in the search result either.  (There is, but it's in a different location than it is for the breed call -- odd.)  This update shows how to handle that issue using `Promise.all`.

Comment: Your code actually solves my problem but can you please help me with more explanation or if possible help me translate to react code. @Scott Sauyet

Comment: Kindly help break this down

Comment: @simplelife: Updated to break it down.

Comment: Thank You @Scott Sauyet